# On what layer DTO translation shoud be implemented?

Tags: java, internationalization, refactoring, dto, clean-architecture

For example, I have a service:

```
@Service
class OrderService {
    OrderDto getOrder(String id) {
      return OrderMapper.toOrderDto(orderRepository.getOrder(id))
   }
}
```

`OrderDto` has the field `String description`

I need to return the correct description depending on locale (en, es, etc.)

Where should I do that translation? Should I do that in the `OrderMapper`? if so, OrderMapper should be a spring component. Or maybe I should create a translator?

```
OrderController -> OrderService 1 -> orderRepository
                                2 -> OrderMapper
```

Should I add a new layer for translation? It looks, that Mapper is not a good place for that(SRP)

Answer (score -1):

[Update]:
You can create a Singleton Mapper, use it in the service layer to do the translation, and implement the mapping logic in the mapper, for that I suggest the use of [MapStruct](https://mapstruct.org/documentation/installation/)

Example:

```
@Mapper
public interface OrderMapper {

  @Mapping(target = "descritpion", source = "descr")
  OrderDto orderToOrderDto(Order order);

  @Mapping(target = "descritpion", source = "descr")
  Order orderDtoToOrder(OrderDto orderDto);
}
```

Do not forget to have the getters and setters implemented, for that I suggest the use of [Lombok](https://projectlombok.org/).